# Eclipse - Glassfish 5 - Error in glassfish-web.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

I try to create a new j2e project running on a glassfish server.
I created the server and am able to run it from eclipse but the project itself has an issue with the glassfish-web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/test-glassfish</context-root>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

I really don't get what is wrong and I didn't find much in my search.

[image]

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a JDK issue, and not required to install a new eclipse.**

**The root cause is the internet not connecting inside eclipse.**

Here are the steps for modifying network inside eclipse:

1. **In eclipse - GoTo --> Preferences --> Network Connections**
2. **Inside "Network Connections" -->  select ActiveProvider = manual**
3. **Click on "Apply & Close".**
4. **Restart eclipse**.

you will get access to Marketplace.

eclipse Preferences screenshot for reference :
**https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flljz.png**

Comment: btw i tested on another laptop where there was no previous installation and I have the same issue. Can it com from my internet connection or firewall ?